# > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle

I installed Android Studio and Flutter. "flutter doctor" says it all OK.
But when I run my first App it comes the following error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\infect_check\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Mike\.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
```

Thank you for your Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Download an older version of the **JDK** and update your **JAVA_HOME** variable. I just downgraded to JDK **9**, and it is now working.